# Unlocked package name changed or package delete option

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, unlocked-package

I have below questions:
Can we change the name of a created unlocked package?
Also can we delete any unlock package which is already created?

Please provide solution if available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is not currently possible to rename or delete an unlocked package or package version. You will want to vote for [this Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lMYmQAM). In the meantime, the best you can do is deprecate the package so it cannot be installed.

Comment: The command of @Carlos below worked for me, so - it is possible to rename a package

Answer (score 1):

You can rename an unlocked package with the following command:

```
sfdx force:package:update -p package-alias -n new-package-name
```

Full reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_package.htm

Answer (score 0):

As of Winter '21 this is now possible to do with the following command:

```
sfdx force:package:delete -p package-id -v targetdevhubusername
```

You may receive an invalid server id error which is a known issue (https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V0000003yQoQAI) also discussed in this thread ([SFDX Package Delete or Package Update - Invalid Server Id](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/327882/sfdx-package-delete-or-package-update-invalid-server-id))